# Django - Can not join 2 models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Problem:** Joining 2 models in Django.

**Error**: Error during template rendering. Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use entity_id.set() instead.

I have read through all the threads on SO. Tried all the suggested solutions, read the Django documentation and think I just must be fundamentally misunderstanding something. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have 2 models. *Entity* and *File*.

An *Entity* can have multiples *Files* but each *File* only has 1 *Entity*.

The primary keys of each table are just auto incrementing integers. Therefore I want to join column **entity_id** from *File* with **entity_id**  from *Entity*. According to the documentation I have set **entity_id** in *File* as a ForeignKey. And I have set **entity_id** as unique in *Entity*

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    pk_entity = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    entity_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)  
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'entities'


class File(models.Model):
    pk_file = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    filename = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)    
    entity_id = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete= models.CASCADE, to_field='entity_id')
```

The view is just trying to render this. I have tried using .all() rather than select_related() but no data renders.

```
class TestListView(ListView):  
    queryset = File.objects.select_related()    
    template_name = "operations/files/test_list.html"
```

And this is the html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <div>       
        <ul>
            {% for x in object_list %}
            <li>             
                {{x}} 
             </li>
            {% empty %}
            <p>Empty</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>      
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: have you tried checking the content of `object_list`, `query_set` and make sure the database is filled? Because `.all()` doesn't care about foreign keys, and if there's an error related to the foreign key it should put you an error message.

Comment: The database is populated. All() returns the File data but not the Entity data. Presently I am using selected_related() as the documentation and other threads on SO suggest this is the correct one to pull in FK

Comment: I would also check whether `object_list` is populated and checking the content of `File.objects.select_related()` on some test.py file to decide whether it's queryset issue or html rendering issue

Answer (score 2):

When using `select_related` you should pass your field name to be selected.

Try this:

```py
class TestListView(ListView):  
    queryset = File.objects.select_related("entity").all()    
    template_name = "operations/files/test_list.html"
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try this it says "entity" not found and that I should use "entity_id" but then when I use "entity_id" a template error is thrown where Django is looking for "entity_id_id" i.e. somewhere an extra _id is being added

Comment: There in no need to declare you FK with `_id` postfix. In your model, you can declare `entity` instread of `entity_id` and then you sill access entity id via `entity_id` @Andy

Comment: In the FK declaration when I change from ```entity_id=``` to ```entity =``` and call as you describe then I get the same error as in the original post

Comment: Add your error traceback @Andy

Comment: I stumbled through this and got it working. There was a warning about name clash. I think the automatic appending of ```_id```  was confusing things.

Your answer was critical to this. So thank you and I will choose this as accepted answer as I am sure it will help others.